# How to pass parameters through forms with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

Beginner question. I have modal box listing suppliers on index. I want to render new purchase form for this supplier (and filter @supplier.products) therefore need to pass supplier_id somehow.

Modal window

```
<% @suppliers.each do |supplier| %>
  <li><%= link_to supplier.name, new_purchase_path(@supplier) %></li>
<% end %>
```

The Form

```
<%= nested_form_for(@purchase) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supplier_id, :class => "mandatory" %>
    <%= @supplier.name %>
    <%= collection_select(:purchase, :supplier_id, Supplier.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
  </div>
```

I get nil error by doing so `undefined method "name" for nil:NilClass`

Not sure if I need to define `@supplier in purchase#new action`

Thanks.

*** Edit ***
What I'm trying to do is create a new form through `http://localhost:3004/purchases/new?supplier_id=2` I can verify through the console that supplier_id is set `Parameters: {"supplier_id"=>"2"}` however when I submit the form it complains about supplier_id being nil.

How to make sure supplier_id is correctly set?

```
def new
@supplier = Supplier.find(params[:supplier_id])
@purchase = current_user.purchases.new(params[:supplier_id => @supplier.id])
@products = @supplier.products

@products.each do |product|
  @purchase.purchase_items.build(:product_id => product.id)
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @purchase }
 end
end
```

Comment: can you put up the appropriate pieces of your controller action too? Where are you using supplier_id to fetch out the supplier etc? :)

Comment: What is this: `params[:supplier_id => @supplier.id]` ? shouldn't that just be `:supplier_id => @supplier.id` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of similarly-named variables and it's confusing.

@suppliers
@supplier
supplier

Where are each of them coming from?

My best guess is that the first modal box should be this:

```
<% @suppliers.each do |supplier| %>
  <li><%= link_to supplier.name, new_purchase_path(supplier) %></li>
<% end %>
```

But your error message seems to indicate that supplier is nil... which makes me wonder about what it is you do to fill @suppliers

If you happen not to *have* any suppliers yet... Supplier.all will also return nil and that might behave badly with the collection_select (ie it'll try to call :name on a supplier when there aren't any yet). So you might have to put something like `if Supplier.count > 1` around that collection-select... or something else appropriate to your business logic.

Comment: Hi Erin, thanks for your reply. Let me update my question with the appropriate piece requested. However I can confirm that there is a couple of suppliers in the Db so the issue does not come from there